# Linq-to-SQL, pass Expression<Func<T, T>> to select method in query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-query-syntax

Suppose, we have next code:

```
public class Dto
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
}    

...

using (var db = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var q = from boss in db.Employees
          from grunt in db.Employees.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == boss.EmployeeID).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new Dto { Id = boss.EmployeeID, Name = grunt.FirstName };
}
```

I want to extract selector as Expression and store it in another place. In method syntax it will look like this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, Employee, Dto>> selector = (boss, grunt) => new Dto
{
  Id = boss.EmployeeID, Name = grunt.FirstName
};

using (var db = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var q = db.Employees.SelectMany(boss => db.Employees.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == boss.EmployeeID).DefaultIfEmpty(), selector);
}
```

Is it possible to convert this LinqToSql method chain to query syntax keeping Expression variable in-place?

**UPD:**

To clarify my question, I'm using DefaultIfEmpty for left join, it's a short form of equal query:

```
using (var db = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var q = from boss in db.Employees
          join stub in db.Employees on boss.EmployeeID equals stub.ReportsTo into stubi
          from grunt in stubi.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new Dto { Id = boss.EmployeeID, Name = grunt.FirstName };
}
```

which works normally, because it compiles using inline Expression. It assigns `null` to Name field when there is no corresponding `grunt`. But if rewrite this query with call to external mapper method, it will be compiled to method call, which will get nullable `grunt` argument and will lead to NullReferenceException:

```
public static Dto GetDto(Employee boss, Employee grunt)
{
  return new Dto
    {
      Id = boss.EmployeeID,
      Name = grunt.FirstName
    };
}

using (var db = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var q = from boss in db.Employees
          join stub in db.Employees on boss.EmployeeID equals stub.ReportsTo into stubi
          from grunt in stubi.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select GetDto(boss, grunt);
}
```

Sure, I can add null-check into mapper method, but what I'm trying to achieve in my DAL is extract selectors into mapper classes and possibly omit null-checks there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the `Expression` - just use the `Func`. This should work:

```
Func<Employee, Employee, Dto> selector = (boss, grunt) => new Dto 
{ 
Id = boss.EmployeeID, Name = grunt.FirstName 
}; 

using (var db = new NorthwindDataContext()) 
{ 
var q = from boss in db.Employees 
        from grunt in db.Employees.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == boss.EmployeeID).DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select selector(boss, grunt)
}
```

Comment: As you can see, here is left join. If use just `Func`, it will throw TargetInvocationException with inner NullReferenceException because of  `grunt` may be equals to null. But it works normally with Expression passed to Select method in method chain format.

Comment: @Harm Are you _sure_ about that? The twin `select` just gets translated into a call to `SelectMany` by the compiler. Anyway, if you're worried about null grunts, _why are you calling DefaultIfEmpty_?

Comment: @Rawling, yes, I'm sure. I'm calling DefaultIfEmpty for left join. I updated the question for clarification.

Comment: @Harm Huh, does `DefaultIfEmpty` give a non-null object with null fields rather than a null object, then? Weird.

Comment: @Rawling, it fails for Linq-to-objects with NRE, but works fine for inline select predicate with Linq-to-SQL. I don't know exactly, why. It's not because DefaultIfEmpty can give non-null object for empty right sequence, but something with Linq-to-SQL selector treating.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use query syntax always, there are cases where you can express computations only with method chains. In this specific case the query syntax would introduce a lambda behind the scenes if the predicate was inline, but you are putting it into a variable so you have no way to specify how that variable should be used, as you would with a lambda, supported by query syntax.